# Reading utf-8 encoded files with fopen C

Tags: c, utf-8, fopen

I have created a text file with following characters for testing utf-8 encoding:

```
%gÁüĳȐʨΘЋЮѦҗԘՔהڳضणணษ༒Ⴃᎃᡧᬐ⁜₪≸☺⛜⺟むヸ㒦㢒
```

I also have written this program in C to open file and read it:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr = fopen("inputtest.txt", "r, ccs=UTF-8");
    char input[50];
    if (ptr == NULL)
        perror("Error opening file");
    else {
        if (fgets(input, 50, ptr) != NULL) {
            puts(input);
        }
        printf(input);
        fclose(ptr);
    }
}
```

If I don't use `ccs=UTF-8`, I will get some unreadable characters. But with it, the program crashes with code `-1073740791`. Also after using `wchar_t` and `fgetws` the program's output was just `%`.
Note: I am using windows 11 and visual studio 2022 and I need to input multi-language characters.

Comment: First, use consistent indentation in *all* your code.  Random variations in indentation make your code impossible to read, *even for you*.  For example, your code will still call `fclose()` if `fopen()` returns `NULL`, but your wildly inconsistent indentation makes that bug hard to spot.

Comment: @AndrewHenle ok, I rewrote code.

Comment: Character strings do not contain information about their encoding.  It is up to your program and applications to support the proper encoding for the data.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/57131654/1216776

Comment: @stark Thank you! That kinda worked and it now prints `%gÁüĳȐʨΘЋЮѦҗԘՔהڳضणணษ༒Ⴃ�` than some random number (e.g. 6.33975e+257) and previous string again. Commenting `printf` will get rid of the second string. So I think, `puts()` also prints everything for some reason.

Comment: I understood, that I should make char array way bigger than the string length is. That solves the problem but `puts()` still outputs string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `fgetws(3)`, instead, and using `setlocale(3)` prior to that.  For one byte characters, you are limited to ascii or at most one byte characters.  And of course, use `wchar_t` characters, instead of `char`.

But, if you use utf-8 encoding, all bytes are read as bytes, and can be printed as bytes.  You can read and write those without interpreting them (except, of course if you want to interpret them):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
}
```

should work:

```
$ a.out <<EOF
> %gÁüĳȐʨΘЋЮѦҗԘՔהڳضणணษ༒Ⴃᎃᡧᬐ⁜₪≸☺⛜⺟むヸ㒦㢒
> EOF
%gÁüĳȐʨΘЋЮѦҗԘՔהڳضणணษ༒Ⴃᎃᡧᬐ⁜₪≸☺⛜⺟むヸ㒦㢒
$ _
```

A better approach (to asciify its utf8 input) is shown below:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define INCORRECT 0xfffd

void out_char(unsigned c)
{
    switch (c) {
    case '\n': case '\r': case '\t': case '\b': case '\f':
        putchar(c);
        return;
    case '\\':
        printf("\\u%04x", c);
        return;
    }
    if (c < 0x80) {
        if (iscntrl(c)) {
            printf("\\u%04x", c);
            return;
        }
        putchar(c);
        return;
    }
    if (c < 0x10000) {
        printf("\\u%04x", c);
        return;
    }
    printf("\\U%08x", c);
    return;
} /* out_char */

int to_ascii()
{
    int c;
    int in    = 0;
    int state = 0x00; /* idle state */

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch (state) {

        case 0x00: /* idle state */
            if (c >= 0xf0) { /* 0b1111xxxx, illegal -- reserved */
                out_char(INCORRECT);
            } else if (c >= 0xe0) { /* 0b1110xxxx, three bytes seq. */
                in = c & 0x0f;
                state = 0x02;
            } else if (c >= 0xc0) { /* 0b110xxxxx, two bytes seq. */
                in = c & 0x1f;
                state = 0x01;
            } else if (c >= 0x80) { /* 0b10xxxxxx, invalid */
                out_char(INCORRECT);
            } else { /* 0b0xxxxxxx */
                out_char(c);
            }
            break;

        case 0x01: /* one to go */
            if (c >= 0xf0) { /* 0b1111xxxx, illegal + illegal */
                out_char(INCORRECT);
                out_char(INCORRECT);
                state = 0x00; /* idle */
            } else if (c >= 0xe0) { /* 0b1110xxxx, illegal */
                out_char(INCORRECT);
                in = c & 0x0f;
                state = 0x02; /* two to go */
            } else if (c >= 0xc0) { /* 0b110xxxxx, illegal */
                out_char(INCORRECT);
                in = c & 0x1f;
                state = 0x01; /* one to go */
            } else if (c >= 0x80) { /* 0x10xxxxxx, legal */
                in <<= 6;
                in |= c & 0x3f;
                out_char(in);
                state = 0x00;
            } else { /* 0x0xxxxxxx, illegal + legal */
                out_char(INCORRECT);
                out_char(c);
                state = 0x00;
            }
            break;

        case 0x02: /* two to go */
            if (c >= 0xf0) { /* 0b1111xxxx, illegal + illegal */
                out_char(INCORRECT);
                out_char(INCORRECT);
                state = 0x00; /* idle */
            } else if (c >= 0xe0) { /* 0b1110xxxx, illegal */
                out_char(INCORRECT);
                in = c & 0x0f;
                state = 0x02; /* two to go */
            } else if (c >= 0xc0) { /* 0b110xxxxx, illegal */
                out_char(INCORRECT);
                in = c & 0x1f;
                state = 0x01; /* one to go */
            } else if (c >= 0x80) { /* 0x10xxxxxx, legal */
                in <<= 6;
                in |= c & 0x3f;
                state = 0x01;
            } else { /* 0x0xxxxxxx, illegal + legal */
                out_char(INCORRECT);
                out_char(c);
                state = 0x00;
            }
            break;
        } /* switch */
    } /* while */
} /* to_ascii */

int main()
{
    to_ascii();
}
```

that, on the given input, will output:

```
$ a.out <<EOF
> %gÁüĳȐʨΘЋЮѦҗԘՔהڳضणணษ༒Ⴃᎃᡧᬐ⁜₪≸☺⛜⺟むヸ㒦㢒
> EOF
%g\u00c1\u00fc\u0133\u0210\u02a8\u0398\u040b\u042e\u0466\u0497\u0518\u0554\u05d4\u06b3\u0636\u0923\u0ba3\u0e29\u0f12\u10a3\u1383\u1867\u1b10\u205c\u20aa\u2278\u263a\u26dc\u2e9f\u3080\u30f8\u34a6\u3892
$ _
```

Comment: Glad to know. Thanks!!! 

Answer (score 0):

You call `printf(input)` in all cases:

- the contents of `input` are indeterminate when `fgets()` fails.  Calling `printf` with such a format string has undefined behavior.
- if `fgets()` succeeded, calling `printf` with a string read from a file is a risky thing.  If the string contains a `%` sign not immediately followed by another `%`, the behavior is undefined as `printf` will look for variable arguments you did not pass.

It is unclear why you have this call, you should just remove it.

Regarding the program's output, whether it will be readable or not depends on the selected terminal encoding.

---

<sub>The extra `, ccs=UTF-8` attribute in the `fopen` mode string is a Microsoft extension to try and help programmers deal with text file encodings.  It is sad to see how much energy has been wasted over the last 30 years to deal with 8-bit to 16-bit conversions for API calls and the like when the rest of the world standardized on UTF-8.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for noticing this. I didn't know about `%` sign so I just put it there. But I still don't understand why `fgets()` or `puts()` outputs characters even when `printf()` is not there.

Comment: `fgets()` does not output anything, it reads a line from the file into the array `input`. `puts()` outputs the contents of `input` and a newline character. The contents of the file looks random to me, it is difficult to tell whether the output is expected or not.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. You are right, the file just contains a bunch of random characters from different languages (and more). If I use this code, it will output 2 strings not 1, so I was confused.